# C# not executing SSIS package in CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, ssis

I'm trying to run a SSIS package within my C# Application. When running the application, I can trigger the CMD, but it only pops up for a fraction of a second. It is not running the SSIS package.

My code looks as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string strCmdText = "/C F: & cd \"path\\to\\package\" & dtexec /f \"Package.dtsx\" /de password";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }
```

The command above works fine in the CMD (of course without escaping backslashes), but is not doing anything when debugging in Visual Studio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Process.Start starts a process, it's not a console window. You *don't* have to use `cmd` to execute `dtexec`, simply call `Process.Start("fullpathtodtexec.exe")`, etc, passing as arguments the arguments you would pass to `dtexec`. Or create a ProcessStartInfo object and set the relevant properties

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PanagiotisKanavos. Hence the following should work, right? `Process.Start("dtexec", "/f \"Package.dtsx\" /de caas");` I Find it strange that the console is only visible for a fraction of a second. In this way, it's hard to debug and see what goes wrong. Above code didn't solve the problem (though is definitely an improvement), any suggestions?

Comment: My bad, you solved it indeed ;) My path to the package was wrongly defined in above comment. Thanks!